# Book recommendation on set theory relations and functions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there any books that is good on set theory , relation and functions and has ample amount of exercises ?

Comment: You can try with [Enderton](https://books.google.it/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&printsec=frontcover) as well as [Jech](https://books.google.it/books?id=GHjmCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) as well as [Moschovakis](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZYFCAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @Mauro: Recommending Jech as an intro is a bit excessive.

Comment: [Naive set theory](https://www.amazon.com/Naive-Set-Theory-Paul-Halmos/dp/1614271313) by Halmos, does contain exercises but sparsely.